# How to import a module to use within a module (ocaml)

Tags: module, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm new to functional programming and was wondering what would be the best way to do this. I have one file (`display.ml`) that has functions that saves, loads, and displays the high score, and another file (`turn.ml`) that has functions to handle playing a turn in a card game. I'm currently trying to tie both of these together in one file called `game.ml`. I made a module in `display.ml` and `turn.ml`, whose contents contains all the functions I previously wrote in the file. I was wondering what would be the best way to import these modules into `game.ml`. I was reading [this](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html), and it seems like the modules have to be defined in the same file that you would like to use it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have three files :

```
cat display.ml
let p x = Printf.printf  "%d" x

cat turn.ml
let t =(+) 1

cat game.ml
open Display
open Turn   
let ()=
  p (t 2 )
```

As you can see, you can "import turn.ml" with open Turn and use the function t inside game.ml

```
To compile :ocamlbuild game.byte
Exexcution :./game.byte
3
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but note that you can use modules without opening them. You can just write `Display.p` and `Turn.t`. Using `open` is something to consider carefully as it has a big effect on the local namespace.